# undefined symbol: initPAnsiStrings

Tags: opensuse

I want to use gcfsplit program that provided in https://www.guralp.com/sw/gcfsplit.shtml
To use this executable compiled program I need to copy libborqt-6.9-qt2.3.so that can be downloaded on this site, to my /usr/lib. I performed this too.
when I am trying to run this program I face with the following error
 gcfsplit: symbol lookup error: gcfsplit: undefined symbol: initPAnsiStrings
I am using openSUSE Leap 15.1

nm -D gcfsplit returns

> ```
>      U calloc
>      U close
>      U close
>      U closedir
>      U ctime
>      U __ctype_get_mb_cur_max 0804b4f0 T @DbgEvalEnd 0804b4e8 T @DbgEvalExcept 0804b4f8 T @DbgEvalFrame 0804b4e0 T @DbgEvalMarker
> ```
>
> 0804b4d8 T @DbgExcNotify
>            U dladdr
>            U dladdr
>            U dladdr
>            U dlclose
>            U dlclose
>            U dlclose
>            U dlerror
>            U dlopen
>            U dlopen
>            U dlopen
>            U dlsym
>            U dlsym
>            U dlsym
>            U dup
>            U __errno_location
>            U euidaccess
>            U exit
>            U fclose
>            U fcntl
>            U fdopen
>            U fflush
>            U fnmatch
>            U fopen
>            U fprintf
>            U free
>            U free
>            U free
>            U ftruncate
>            U ftruncate
>            U getcwd
>            U getenv
>            U getenv
>            U getpid
>            U gnu_get_libc_version
>            U iconv
>            U iconv_close
>            U iconv_open
>            U initializePIntArray
>            U initializePPointArray
>            U initPAnsiStrings
>            U initPWideStrings
>            U kill
>            U __libc_start_main
>            U localeconv
>            U localtime_r
>            U lseek
>            U __lseek
>            U __lxstat
>            U malloc
>            U malloc
>            U mblen
>            U mblen
>            U memcpy
>            U memset
>            U mmap
>            U munmap
>            U nl_langinfo
>            U nl_langinfo
>            U open
>            U open
>            U opendir
>            U pipe 08052388 T Portions Copyright (c) 1983,2002 Borland Software Corporation
>            U printf
>            U pthread_getspecific
>            U pthread_getspecific
>            U pthread_key_create
>            U pthread_mutexattr_destroy
>            U pthread_mutexattr_init
>            U pthread_mutexattr_settype
>            U pthread_mutex_destroy
>            U pthread_mutex_init
>            U pthread_mutex_lock
>            U pthread_mutex_unlock
>            U pthread_once
>            U pthread_self
>            U pthread_setspecific
>            U raise
>            U read
>            U read
>            U readdir_r
>            U readlink
>            U realloc
>            U setlocale
>            U setlocale
>            U sigaction
>            U sigaddset
>            U strcasecmp
>            U strcoll
>            U strdup
>            U strerror_r
>            U strlen
>            U strncmp
>            U strtok
>            U strverscmp 0806d25c A @Sysinit@ResHash 0806d214 A @Sysinit@ResStr 0806d154 A @Sysinit@ResSym
>            U time
>            U time
>            U towupper
>            U vfprintf
>            U wcscoll
>            U wordexp
>            U wordfree
>            U write
>            U write
>            U __xstat
>            U __xstat

Thanks,

Comment: ldd -d gcfsplit returnes

Comment: linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7798000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf774a000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf7745000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf756a000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7799000)

Comment: nm -D gcfsplit also returns

Answer (score 0):

problem was that I didn't have some 32bit libraries like libSM.

So I used strace command to figure out which libes are missed.
"strace ./gcfsplit "

I followed the output and installed libs that were missing.